# R loop - Pick up the next input and store the output into data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

So I'm a newbie to R and basically I'm looking to a large sum of regressions from taking data from one data frame and storing the output into a new data frame but to also create a loop to automatically "pick up the next input" and skip the duplicates.

I've attached a photo of what my data looks like.

This is my code to run the regressions

```
#inputs
Airport = "ABZ"


#choose target airport & nation GDP
df <- subset(Elasticities_Study, Airport_Code==Airport)

#log-log
df <- data.frame(df$Year, df$Region, 
             df$Airport_Code, log(df$Passengers, 10), log(df$GDP, 10))
colnames(df) <- c("Year", "Region", 
                         "Airport", "Passengers", "GDP")

#regression
fit <- lm(df$Passengers ~ df$GDP)

#store the coefficient
coefficient <-coefficients(fit)
elasticity <- coefficient["df$GDP"]

#store the p_value
p <- function (fit) {
  if (class(fit) != "lm") stop("Not an object of class 'lm' ")
  f <- summary(fit)$fstatistic
  p <- pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F)
  attributes(p) <- NULL
  return(p)
}

p_value <- p(fit)

#store the r_squared
r_squared <- summary(fit)$r.squared

#save regression output into data frame
Regression_Output <- data.frame(df[1,2], df[1,3], 
                            elasticity, p_value, r_squared)
colnames(Regression_Output) <- c("Region", "Airport", "Elasticity", "P-
Value", "R_Squared")
```

Could someone please help! Thanks!

[image: rawdata]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldn't comment on the above answer (my answer belongs more of a comment but I don't really have permissions for that yet).

You can use a variation of the loop Ben_its performed, but instead of using a numeric value for i, have the loop iterate by Airport code.  Its messy code but its how my brain works

First create a blank data.frame to store your new results solutions.
Then create a vector with all of your airport codes.
Set the loop to loop through that vector of airport codes you provide it.

Within the loop, the first thing it is doing is subsetting the data based on that first airport code.  So in your list, it will take only the airports with Airport_Code == item #1 on your vector of codes.  Then it will run your regression and you will tell it which values to take from the summary, etc.  Once it has the values you want, it stores it into the vector solution new_data, which is then rbind-ed to the blank data.frame we created for the solutions.  That last line is where it is simply creating a new results data.frame by taking the previous object of the results data.frame and adding the new row of the solutions you just got based on the subsetted data by airport code.  Then, it iterates through the next airport code in your codes vector.

```
your_data = data.frame(source data)
## Create empty data.frame to store solutions. We will use the loop and rbind to constantly add a row of solutions with each iteration of the loop
results = data.frame()
codes = c(all of your airport codes)
for (i in codes){
    ## here you use the variable of the loop to subset your whole dataset based on that airport code
    byairportcode = subset(your_data,your_data$Airport_Code == i)
    ## All operations listed in your post, creating a vector of your desired information/solutions for each line
    new_data = something(parameters)
    ###combine this new data with your list of solutions by airport code 
    results = rbind(results,new_data)
}
```

You shouldn't need to eliminate any duplicates, because you have subsetted the data by airport code already, such that each entry in your results frame is each individual airport code's results of the regression.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `by` to slice the large dataframe by every *Airport Code* and pass each as subsetted dataframe object into a called function like your regression processing.

Final output will be a list of dataframes with equal length to distinct *Airport Codes* and each item of list named by corresponding airport code.

**Assign Functions**

```
# store the p_value
p <- function (fit) {
   if (class(fit) != "lm") stop("Not an object of class 'lm' ")
   f <- summary(fit)$fstatistic
   p <- pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F)
   attributes(p) <- NULL

   return(p)
}

# run regressions
regression_process <- function(df) {

   #log-log
   df <- data.frame(Year=df$Year, Region=df$Region, Airport=df$Airport_Code,
                    Passengers=log(df$Passengers, 10), GDP=log(df$GDP, 10))
   #regression
   fit <- lm(df$Passengers ~ df$GDP)

   #store the coefficient
   coefficient <-coefficients(fit)
   elasticity <- coefficient["df$GDP"]

   p_value <- p(fit)

   #store the r_squared
   r_squared <- summary(fit)$r.squared

   #save regression output into data frame
   data.frame(Region=df[1,2], Airport=df[1,3], Elasticity=elasticity, 
              P_Value=p_value, R_Squared=r_squared)
}
```

**Run by()** *(creates a list of named dataframes for each Airport Code)*

```
regression_list <- by(Elasticities_Study, Elasticities_Study$Airport_Code, 
                      FUN=regression_process)

regression_list$ABE   # FIRST REGRESSION DATAFRAME ELEMENT
regression_list$ABI   # SECOND REGRESSION DATAFRAME ELEMENT
regression_list$ABJ   # THIRD REGRESSION DATAFRAME ELEMENT
...
```